# Bug? Using addBcc on Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template doesn't seem to work

Tags: email, email-templates, transactional

The way I use it (Magento EE 1.12):

```
    $transactional = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    foreach($ccEmails as $ccEmail) {
        $transactional->addBcc(trim($ccEmail));
    }

    try{

        $transactional->sendTransactional($transactionalTemplateId, $sender, $recipientEmail, $recipientName, $vars, $storeId);

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        throw $e;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, nevermind, it's not a Magento bug. I've debugged it and it turns out that `Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Template` has extended the `addBcc` method, but doesn't add it to the `Zend_Mail` instance (which `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` does).

I've emailed ebizmarts support with the fix:

The `addBcc` method in `app/code/community/Ebizmarts/Mandrill/Model/Email/Template.php` should have the following code added right after the function declaration:

```
    //Check if should use Mandrill Transactional Email Service
    if(FALSE === Mage::helper('mandrill')->useTransactionalService()){
        return parent::addBcc($bcc);
    }
```

Otherwise bcc will not be set in the `Zend_Mail` instance when the send method is called in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`.

For now, I've created a module that rewrites and extends the Mandrill module and overrides the `addBcc` method.

Comment: Can you set your awnser as the awnser that solved the bug?

Comment: Does it work as expected? As far as I know, Zend_Mail::addBcc() is bugged and adds email to "To" field too http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8723 and therefore useless.

Comment: answering one's own question can only be done after 2 days @SanderMangel

Comment: @Zyava, interesting, it does seem to work for me, I can't see the other recipients when looking at the email in Gmail, but then again, the server is using Linux, and the bug only seems to happen on Windows..